# Login modal - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I make a modal to login, if username and password are correct another activity will open, but it always gives a wrong answer even i put a correct username and password.

This is my code :

```
public void Admin(View view){

    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_login, null);
    final EditText username = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
    final EditText password = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_password);

    final String user = username.getText().toString().trim();
    final String pass = password.getText().toString().trim();
    Button submit = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

    final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(user.equals("admin") && (pass.equals("admin"))){
                try{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,InputActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your Username and Password is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    mBuilder.setView(mView);

    dialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `username` and `password` variables inside the `onClickedListener()`. This will gonna fetch the current values of the variables. Declare it outside the `Listener` and put the implementation inside. Observe and try this code. This might help.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
 Button b1,b2;
   EditText ed1,ed2;

   TextView tx1;
   int counter = 3;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
  ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
  ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

  b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
  tx1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
  tx1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

  b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        if(ed1.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&
           ed2.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {try{
                Intent intent = new   Intent(MainActivity.this,InputActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
           }else{
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong 
                 Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              tx1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              tx1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
              counter--;
              tx1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

              if (counter == 0) {
                 b1.setEnabled(false);
              }
           }
     }
  });

  b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
     }
  });
}
}
```

Comment: Its about if, your if helps me

Comment: @husen Next time try to print every instance of a variable content before doing comparison. That will help you to check of what are the values of your variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the user and password values before the submit button onClick event is called, therefore the values are always going to be empty. You can fix this by moving the following lines inside the `onClick(View view)` method:

`final String user = username.getText().toString().trim();
 final String pass = password.getText().toString().trim();`

Answer (score 0):

This 2 line will return empty String

```
final String user = username.getText().toString().trim();
final String pass = password.getText().toString().trim();
```

Because you are getting text form `EditText` before user type anything.

What you actually need? You have to collect text from `EditText` after submit button click.

So Use thouse line inside `OnCLickListener`

```
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        user = username.getText().toString().trim();
        pass = password.getText().toString().trim();
        if(user.equals("admin") && (pass.equals("admin"))){
            try{
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,InputActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your Username and Password is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```